# Closed Captions missing when converting from mp4 to ts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, file-formats, closed-captioning

This is a follow-up question from my previous question [HERE](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27854/errors-in-converting-mp4-to-ts-with-ffmpeg/27855#27855). I'm trying to convert a caption-embedded .`mp4` video into a .`ts` file, simply changing the container format. But once I convert the video, the caption looks different. Not sure what's going on.

[Here](http://dropbox.com/s/697c7tuqgkc0bv0/test.mp4?dl=0) is the sample .`mp4` video. At second 00:34" for example, you see the caption says `GARBLED CAPTION INSERTED`. But that's not there in the converted `.ts` file.

What's happening? Any clues?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtitles in the MP4 is a mov_text (tx3g) stream which isn't supported in MPEG-TS.

MPEG-TS support either DVD subtitles or DVB teletext. The former is a bitmap subtitle format and ffmpeg can't convert text to bitmap. FFmpeg has no encoder for the latter. Your best bet is to burn the subtitles but this means re-encoding the video.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf subtitles=in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.ts
```

Comment: what is the caption format for a regular .ts file viewable on VLC? For example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1unlmyketqnv1e/test.ts?dl=0
The format is different from the one created from your command.

Comment: My command makes the captions part of the image. In your sample, the captions are embedded as an element within the video bitstream. ffmpeg can't convert subtitles from a separate stream into those.

Comment: I see. Got it. Tnx.